# How to host a different react app on a particular view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodebb

I'm exploring options for what I want to do.

I have a create-react-app-based application and am looking to integrate another React App (NodeBB; running on localhost:port2) as a forum on localhost:port/forum.

It looks like I can use parcel as a bundler/webpack to embed it into the main application. I was wondering if there's a neater way that doesn't cause ongoing maintenence issues and what are the security implications. There also appears to be frontend microservices (e.g. SingleSPA). I'll need to connect the two via oath2 to pass user credentials to the second app.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.